# Asp.Net core (net6) identity external login providers errors when using on different pc-s

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm learning asp.net core and I was following tutorials about identity and external login providers. I have succeded to create extrenal google and ms accounts for testing and locally it is working fine.

I have published test app to my VPN IIS public server to see how it is working (I have other apps there), but I started to have some illogical issues and I don't understand where the problem is.

I can sign in with ms account or google account to one computer.
If i try the same on other computer I'm getting "error 400 redirect_uri_mismatch" with google and almost the same for msaccount:
AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'https://myserver/mysite/signin-microsoft' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application.

Just to add that, on msaccount response, I can see clause that 'Reply address did not match because of case sensitivity'. But that is nonsense because I have signed in with other msaccount (have 2 private accounts for google and for ms for testing) onto different computer and there was working fine.
Just to be sure I have entered proper casing return url address to azure dev portal, and same was happening. it seems like after app publish, first pc which gets msaccount / google user over external login blocks other pc..

I don't understand why extrenal login is working for one pc. First what comes to mind is that beacuse it is a test project and I have not verified domain (etc..) on google / microsoft and that there are some limitations for signing users in (perhaps need to pay??).
But, please, can someone confirm this? Or someone have the idea what is happening?

Tnx!
Renato

Comment: Still not sure what is happening, but I have added 2 return url's for site per provider, one with all letters lowercase and one with letters exactly how it is set up in my publish settings.. Now it seems that it is working fine.. Perhaps I was inserting url in browser's address bar not caring about letter casing.. 
So it seems there are no restricitons for testing with few users for both external login providers.. 
As I recall, I have done something similar while ago with asp.net 4.5, but didn't had described issues..

Comment: Hi @Renato, are you sure you have configure the redirect uri in the google configuration? check this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420434/authorization-error-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-on-c-sharp